# Add array element to an array formed by database query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am building a phonebook application that will generate a list of extensions from our phone system. The phone system has two elements; "name" and "extension". I would like to separate the name into first name and last name. I have already done this with the following:

```
list($ln,$fn) = explode(' ',$contact[1],2);
```

The problem is, I would like to add $ln and $fn to the array that is formed from the database query. The reason for this is because I am creating a json from the array. I have tried the following, but it does not seem to add the fname and lname element to the array:

```
$contact_array = array();
while ($contact=mysql_fetch_array($QUERYresult))
{
 if(preg_match('/\s/',$contact[1]))
 {
  //$count++;
  $contact_array[] = $contact;
  list($ln,$fn) = explode(' ',$contact[1],2);
  $contact['fname'] = $fn;
  $contact['lname'] = $ln;
 }
 fwrite($myJSON, json_encode($contact_array));
```

The output of this array only returns the database query, which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [extension] => 1000
            [name] => Extension 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [extension] => 1001
            [name] => Extension 2
        )
    )
```

Comment: Please stop using the `mysql_` DB library. It was discontinued and deprecated years ago, and removed entirely in PHP7, mostly due to security issues. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` asap.

Comment: The _value_ of `$contact` is added to `$contact_array` when you do `$contact_array[] = $contact;`. It's not added by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be mainly that you're adding the values after you've already passed the original version of $contact into $contact_array. So the extra values you add aren't included in that. Try moving those lines to before you do `$contact_array[] = $contact;`:

```
if(preg_match('/\s/',$contact[1]))
{
  //$count++;
  list($ln,$fn) = explode(' ',$contact[1],2);
  $contact['fname'] = $fn;
  $contact['lname'] = $ln;
  $contact_array[] = $contact;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was my problem!

Comment: @Intrepid no problem. Please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you - thanks :-)